# Azure functions app and Web jobs with service bus triggers missing some messages while processing

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-webjobs, azure-servicebus-queues

I am working on both azure functions and azure web jobs.

What I am trying to do is, sending messages to the Service bus topic and from there, the message is handled in both the below,

- First by Azure function - Reads from one subscription and app sends the
  message to cosmos DB
- Secondly by Azure web jobs - Reads from another subscription    and send messages
  to a Azure Blob storage.

Both of them are using the azure service bus trigger.

SO if there is a very less number of messages like 1 to 5 in a sec it will get processed. But if I send like 30-40 messages at the same time both function app and web jobs missing some messages, I mean if I send like 30 messages and check blob it shows only 25 messages were received .

But when I add an azure function app that runs on time trigger works perfectly with count as 30 sent -30 processed, but I really don't want to use time trigger as it taking too many hits in a day.

It will be great full if someone can help me.

***Function Trigger:***

```cs
        public static void ProcessArchiveQueueMessage([ServiceBusTrigger("*****", "*****", Connection = "ServiceBusConnectionString")] string message, ILogger log)
        {
            ArchiveDll.ProcessArchiveTopic("****", log);
        }
```

***Dll code :***

```cs
       subscriptionClient.OnMessageAsync(m =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        Stream stream = m.GetBody<Stream>();
                        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream);
                        topicData = reader.ReadToEnd();
                        var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(topicData);

                        StoreJsoninBlob(cloudContainer, stream, jObj);

                        StoreInCosmosDB(log, jObj);

                        subscriptionClient.Complete(m.LockToken);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        subscriptionClient.DeadLetter(m.LockToken);
                    }

                    return Task.CompletedTask;

                }, new Microsoft.ServiceBus.Messaging.OnMessageOptions()
                {
                    AutoComplete = false,
                    MaxConcurrentCalls = 1
                });
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {

            }
        }
```

Comment: Is the message diappear or still exsit?

Comment: What is the time to live(TimeToLive), you have set for the service bus message?

Comment: Hi @BowmanZhu there are consumed from a service bus and not reached to blob, i mean they are gone

Comment: @BowmanZhu  So when I send 100 messages to the service bus function app which runs on service bus queue triggers and reads the messages and saves them to the blob. But when I check the number of messages reached to blob its not 100% some of the messages are missing.

Comment: Update -- I was able to fix this thanks.

Comment: @SaiVallap Hi, Sai Vallap. Thank for your contribution. Can you share you solution?

Comment: i Removed some sections of code from the above dll .pasting the lastest code

Comment: In other words, the code that runs inside an Azure function must be synchronous.  Don’t exit the function before your job is done.

Answer (score 0):

all below is the latest code I am using to overcome the stated issue.

```
public static void ProcessArchiveTopic(string subscriptionName, ILogger log, string message)
{

  log.LogInformation("Registering message listener for " + subscriptionName);

  //Below method is triggered every time when a new message is read from queue.

  CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BlobConnectionString"]);
  CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
  CloudBlobContainer cloudContainer = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["BlobContainerName"]);
  cloudContainer.CreateIfNotExists();

  try
  {
      #region"function app reading message"

      log.LogInformation("Processing message for subscription: " + subscriptionName);
      var jObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(message);
      log.LogInformation("Converted message to Json");
      
      #endregion

      StoreJsoninBlob(cloudContainer, GenerateStreamFromString(message), jObj);
      StoreInCosmosDB(log, jObj);
  }
```